# Adding User controls on runtime - accessing the controls

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I'm trying to add some user controls on a page. Thats easy, I just do it like this.

```
UserControl block = (categoryblock) LoadControl("categoryblock.ascx");
Panel1.Controls.Add(block);
```

But i want to access the label controls and more that are inside the categoryblock.ascx.
How would i do that ?

I cant do it like this,

> `block.l_itemName.text = "blabla";`

I managed to user FindControl("l_itemName") but i would rather like to have the intellisense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create following property in your user control:

```
public string ItemName() {
   get() {
        return l_itemName.text;
   }

    set(String value) {
        l_itemName.text = value;
    }    
}
```

This will make you able to do `block.ItemName = ""`or `string temp = block.ItemName`

I hope this will help

Comment: I dont get this to work, I cant get the property to show up. I do get it though if i do this. "categoryblock block = new categoryblock();" - block.ItemName ....

Comment: Got it to work by casting it first like so. ((categoryblock)block).ItemName = "bla";

Comment: nice, I'm glad that it helped. if it resolved your problem, mark it as anwer.